Was the book of Revelation originally written in Ancient Hebrew?
If John was a Hebrew, would it be right to suspect that he wrote his original revelation on a scroll in Hebrew, pre-100 AD?

Highly unlikely. The document itself says it is to be read in seven churches in Asia. The majority (overwhelmingly so?) of the intended audience would not know Hebrew. The idea the first scroll was Hebrew means it would have to be translated into Greek and would be subject to misinterpretation, a process at odds with 22:18-19. The "Hebraisms" in the book are a direct result of the many OT references used in Revelation.

Quite possibly for a number of reasons. However, many texts in Hebrew were simply translations from Greek. But, an authentic copy of Revelation written in Hebrew may indeed have been found!

“In 1806, Claudius Buchanan found two Hebrew New Testament manuscripts
in a Jewish synagogue in Cochin, India. Together these two manuscripts
contain all the books of the New Testament in Hebrew, compiled from
various different sources. Today, these are known as Ms. Oo.1.16 and
Ms. Oo.1.32 of the Cambridge University Library.”

You can download a free PDF of the translation from this website:
https://www.hebrewgospels.com/revelation
I have done so and I'm studying the reasons why the Rensburg's are convinced that this manuscript is an authentic Hebrew copy rather than a translation.
Some of the reasons include exact quotes from the Tanakh, word puns that exist only in Hebrew, and other linguistic evidences.
External Comment: Sorry to say but this is a translation from a Dutch statenvertaling to Hebrew from 1757-1760.
My Comment: When looking at both the Greek and Hebrew side-by-side, it's obvious in many places that the Hebrew was NOT translated from the Greek! There are significant words and phrases added, deleted, and substituted.
The substitutions are puzzling in some cases. For example, in Revelation 21:16, the Greek word stadia would have to have been bizarrely translated as "graves of the field." I would ask two questions: (1) What was the word used in Dutch, and (2) How would one be able to determine which direction the translation took place: Dutch-to-Hebrew or Hebrew-to-Dutch? I would point out that the Dutch had a presence in southern India including Cochin from 1605 to 1825.
We see these differences even in the title of the book! The title in Greek is "Revelation" (from Apokalypsis) while the Hebrew title is "The Secrets," or "The Mysteries," or even "The Hidden Counsels" (from Eleh Ha-Sodot). How do you get from Apokalypsis to "Eleh Ha-Sodot?" Would you translate the title of a novel from "A Detective Revelation" to "A Detective Mystery" or is the reverse more likely? Again, I'm still studying the differences and weighing likelihoods, but I've been starting to lean toward the Hebrew as a copy of the original.
I'd also note that the translations of "the Hebrew gospels" that I've examined are obviously translated from Greek to Hebrew along with doctrinal corruptions. For example, the Hebrew translation of the "Son of Man" in Greek was rendered "Son of the Virgin" in a Hebrew gospel manuscript.

"Exact quotes from the Tanakh" - if you're translating a translation of a quote back to its original language, of course you're going to look up and use the original quote. You'd expect quotations from the Septuagint to be replaced with quotations from the Tanakh in a Greek->Hebrew translation, especially since anyone who'd be making such a translation would almost certainly know the Tanakh well. That's not really evidence of anything more than competent translation.

Agreed, but the same logic is true if the original were written in Greek. In that case, you would think that the quotes would have been copied directly from the Septuagint. Also note that the Greek of Revelation is the roughest in the New Testament. Please do check out the linguistic evidences presented by the Rensburgs. Again, I'm still investigating this manuscript myself to give it a fair chance.

The reverse isn't necessarily true, an author who knew the Tanakh in Hebrew but was writing in Greek might well translate himself and thus differ from the Septuagint. And, well, clearly someone did write in Greek and didn't always quote the Septuagint exactly. And sure, I don't dispute that there might be other evidence, I just don't think this specific point tells us much either way.

The Hebrew Matthew of Shem Tob is instructive. Tob wrote to educate Jews who rejected the Christian claim Jesus was the Christ. He translated Matthew into Hebrew so people who believed as he did could refute Christian claims. He chose Matthew since that Gospel was written for Jews and is particularly oriented to OT prophecies Christians claimed were fulfilled by Jesus. Given the extensive use of the OT in Revelation, it is not surprising Judaism saw the benefit/need of a Hebrew version, either as another apocalyptic work or to understand Christian "errors" in their understanding of the OT.

The idea a single Hebrew manuscript found in a Jewish synagogue over a thousand miles from the seven churches in Asia would have preserved the original message, defies reason.

Yes, I often like to defy reason! ;-) However, do you know where the Apostle Thomas went as a missionary after the resurrection of Jesus?

Let's be clear about what is known about John:
The author:

The author names himself as simply "John" in the text, but his precise
identity remains a point of academic debate. Second-century Christian
writers such as Papias of Hierapolis, Justin Martyr, Irenaeus, Melito
of Sardis, Clement of Alexandria, and the author of the Muratorian
fragment identify John the Apostle as the John of Revelation.
Modern scholarship generally takes a different view, with many considering that nothing can be known about the author except that he
was a Christian prophet. Modern theological scholars characterize
the Book of Revelation's author as "John of Patmos". The bulk of
traditional sources date the book to the reign of the Roman emperor
Domitian (AD 81–96), which evidence tends to confirm. 
[1]

The Language:

To anyone who knows the Greek language, it is immediately clear that
the author of the book of Revelation had not mastered idiomatic Greek
of his day. Rather, his native language was Hebrew. This has led some
scholars to argue that the book of Revelation was originally written
in Hebrew, and later translated into Greek. Others have contended
that its original language was Aramaic, which was later translated
into Greek. However, neither of these views has gained widespread
acceptance among scholars, because neither accounts for all the data
presented in the book itself. Charles is undoubtedly correct when he
states: “while he [the author of the book of Revelation] writes in
Greek, he thinks in Hebrew.” Thus, meanings of words, tenses, cases,
and syntactical constructions which do not make sense in the Greek of
the book of Revelation, make excellent sense when the Hebrew behind
them is understood. [2]

Hebrew thought but Greek language:
This perspective is that while the book was written in Greek, the author was thinking in Hebrew. This means that the meanings of words, tenses, cases, and syntactical constructions in the Greek text of the Book of Revelation make more sense when understood from a Hebrew perspective.
Overall there are 3 points to consider:

Greek origin: The majority view among scholars is that the Book of
Revelation was written directly in Koine Greek, the common language
of the eastern Mediterranean region during the first century AD.
Support:

The majority of existing manuscripts of the Book of Revelation are in Greek.
The book was likely intended for a Greek-speaking audience.
Koine Greek was the lingua franca of the eastern Mediterranean region.

During the time when the Book of Revelation was written (late first century AD), Koine Greek was the lingua franca of the eastern Mediterranean region. It was the language of commerce, literature, and the early Christian Church. Therefore, it would make sense for the author to write in Greek to reach a wider audience.
Associate Professor of New Testament at Denver Seminary in Denver, Colorado, David L. Mathewson's writing:

summarizes what many consider grammatical irregularities in
Revelation’s Greek. These are often thought to show a Semitic
influence on the author’s language, and to perhaps suggest
that he knew Greek only as a second language. Some propose
that the writer used a distinctive type of Jewish Greek, that
the irregularities show a reliance on the Old Testament, or
that they perhaps indicate that he was intentionally flouting
the established patterns of Greek usage. Recent studies,
however, show that it is more likely that the writer was
simply using a form of Greek that was common in his social
context. [3]


Hebrew origin: Some scholars argue that the Book of Revelation was
originally written in Hebrew and then translated into Greek.
Support:

The Greek used contains many Hebraisms, or linguistic features typical of Hebrew.


Aramaic origin: A minority of scholars contend that the book was
originally written in Aramaic, which was then translated into Greek.
This view, however, has not gained widespread acceptance.






References




1
Wikipedia contributors. (2024, August 1). Book of Revelation. Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation


2
OT-Revelation. (n.d.). https://www.studyjesus.com/Religion_Library/Johannine_Studies/15_O_T_Revelation.htm


3
Mathewson, David L., 'Revelation’s Use of the Greek Language', in Craig R. Koester (ed.), The Oxford Handbook of the Book of Revelation (2020; online edn, Oxford Academic, 8 Oct. 2020), https://doi.org/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780190655433.013.6, accessed 6 Aug. 2024.




Many seem to miss the fact that the New Testament writers were mostly bi-lingual (Hebrew/Greek).

+1 While I don't agree with several conclusions, it's still an excellent, well researched answer! And it might indeed be the correct one. :-)
